# Docker compose Rails + Oracle DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to create a docker-compose file that will start a Rails 3.2.13 server and link it to an Oracle DB. So far I have been unable to make the connection from Rails to the Oracle DB. This is the error from Rails

```
oci8.c:513:in oci8lib_191.so: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (OCIError)
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    app:
        image: local-rails:0.0.1
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - "${PWD}:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - db
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    db:
        image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
        environment:
          - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
        ports:
            - "49160:22"
            - "49161:1521"
```

#### Variables in my Dockerfile

```
ENV RAILS_ENV local

# Notice the use of "db" service name as the HOST
ENV RAILS_DB (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db)(PORT=49161))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)))

# I've also tried setting DATABASE_URL directly w/ no yml config
# ENV DATABASE_URL db:49161/xe
```

#### database.yml

```
local:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: <%= RAILS_DB %>
  username: ****
  password: ****
```

I have successfully started both services separately - Rails pointing to external Oracle DB with known working configurations. I have also been able to connect to the containerized Oracle DB via Oracle SQL Developer. The problem is getting them to talk to one another.

Comment: It seems that your `links` configuration is working. `keyforms` service can talk to `oracledb`. **ORA-12154** is a common error related to a file named as `tnsnames.ora` which is a configuration file of Oracle. I can't help you further now but you can check this error code on Google where you will find a lot of results. Hope this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVJ1xO2V7Dc

Comment: I should mention that I am able to connect to this database using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: `depends_on` also implies an entry in `links`, so no need for both.

Comment: I think the docker setup is correct and you are having issues with oracle configuration.

Comment: I think you may be right about that Grimmy. I will have our DBAs look at the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by declaring the env variable `RAILS_DB` to the docker-compose file `environment` declaration instead of declaring it in the Dockerfile. Here's what I did to get Rails working with an Oralce DB locally.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    app:
        image: rails-app:0.0.1
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - "${PWD}:/home/app"
        environment:
            RAILS_ENV: local
            # Note the use of "db" as the HOST
            RAILS_DB: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)))
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - network
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    db:
        image: sath89/oracle-12c
        ports:
            - 1521:1521
        volumes:
            - oracle/data:/u01/app/oracle
        networks:
            - network
        environment:
            - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
            - WEB_CONSOLE=false
            - ORACLE_SID=xe
```

#### database.yml

```
local:
    adapter: oracle_enhanced
    database: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB'] %>
    username: user
    password: pw
    encodeing: utf8
```

#### Dockerfile

In order to use this, you must first download 3 files from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) and put them in a new directory in your project called "oracle".

1. oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
2. oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
3. oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Now you may refer to them as I do below.

```
FROM ruby:1.9.3

EXPOSE 3000

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get install alien -y \
    && apt-get install freetds-dev -y \
    && apt-get install libaio1

COPY ./oracle /home/oracle

# Get these files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
RUN alien -i /home/oracle/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm \
    && alien -i /home/oracle/oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm \
    && alien -i /home/oracle/oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
ENV PATH ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${ORACLE_HOME}/lib
ENV ORACLE_SID=xe

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY Gemfile* ./

RUN bundle install

RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /home/app/tmp/pids/*
```

This will only get you started. You'll have to configure the database users, tablespaces etc. Remember to run your migrations.

While this will get anyone who wants to run Rails with an Oracle DB locally, keep in mind that you may have to tweak some of my settings in order to get it to work for your specific setup. Hopefully this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Using links in docker is deprecated: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

In my project we are using custom networks in docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    ...
    networks:
      - my_network_name
  db:
    ...
    networks:
      - my_network_name

networks:
    my_network_name:
        driver: bridge
```

After running containers you can verify that connection is working:

```
$ docker-compose exec app bash
[root@9939116aec31 /]# ping db
PING db (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nettest_db_1.nettest_my_network_name (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
64 bytes from nettest_db_1.nettest_my_network_name (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
^C
--- db ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
```